# To avoid unintended merges, git-flow aborted

Tags: git, git-flow

We are using [git-flow](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow/wiki).  We work on several different feature branches and keep getting this error:

```
develop|✔ ; git flow feature pull origin RWT-6-valves
Trying to pull from 'feature/RWT-6-valves' while currently on branch 'develop'.
To avoid unintended merges, git-flow aborted.
Fatal:
```

Generally, reverting to an earlier version of develop works.  However, this is a pain. Thus the question:

***How to avoid this message in the future?***

Answer (score 7):

I have seen this message too. This is how I am dealing with:

First of all, try sync:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git push

git checkout develop
git pull
git push
```

After that, you can try the command again:

```
git flow feature checkout MY_FEATURE_NAME
```

If the problem persist, try this:

```
git checkout develop
git flow feature track MY_FEATURE_NAME
git flow feature checkout MY_FEATURE_NAME
git pull origin feature/MY_FEATURE_NAME
```

I don't know explain why this error happens. But, I hope this commands can help you to deal with.

If you really want to know why this message is happening, maybe a good first step to do it is look under the hood, and study the source-code of the git flow here https://github.com/raoulmillais/hgflow/blob/master/git-flow-feature#L495.

Comment: I'll try the next time this happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because you don't have the *RWT-6-valves* local branch.

You have to create the local branch

```
$ git flow feature track RWT-6-valves
Branch feature/RWT-6-valves set up to track remote branch feature/RWT-6-valves from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'feature/RWT-6-valves'

Summary of actions:
- A new remote tracking branch 'feature/RWT-6-valves' was created
- You are now on branch 'feature/RWT-6-valves'
```

Then you can use the *pull* command

```
$  git flow feature pull origin RWT-6-valves
Pulled origin's changes into feature/RWT-6-valves.
```